# Assets + skipBytes performance

Tags: java, android, performance

```
DataInputStream istream = new DataInputStream(inputstream);
istream.skipBytes(offset);
int value = istream.readInt();
```

When the `inputstream` is from `getAssets().open("abc")` and the file is big (up to 20mb), such simple seek+read takes much time to complete (~250ms on my android phone).

When I first copy the file to `getCacheDir().getPath()` the same code will take less than 1ms (if you ignore the startup time for copying ~3sec). Plus the app will use more space, once from the copy and once from the asset.

I only read read about 6 values (`readInt()`) on different locations.

Now to my question, is it possible to improve the performance of the assets skipByte? If yes how? If not is there an alternative, instead of copying the file?

Comment: Can't you use a `SeekableByteChannel` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a working alternative instead of copying assets.

### Example Code

```
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor fd_description = getAssets().openFd("test.raw");
        String apk_path = getPackageResourcePath(); //maybe getPackageCodePath() ?
        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(apk_path, "r");
        file.seek(fd_description.getStartOffset());
        String value = file.readLine();
        Log.e("RAW ACCESS", "READ:" + value);
        file.seek(fd_description.getStartOffset());
        value = file.readLine();
        Log.e("RAW ACCESS", "READ:" + value);
    } catch (IOException exp){
        Log.e("RAW ACCESS", "ERROR:"+exp.toString());
    }
```

### Some Info

`getPackageResourcePath()` returns the path to your APK

`getAssets().openFd("test.raw")` returns the asset informations you need to find the data in the APK

Your asset starts at `fd_description.getStartOffset()` and ends at `fd_description.getStartOffset()+fd_description.getLength()`

With `if (fd_description.getLength() != fd_description.getDeclaredLength())` you can check if the asset is compressed..

### Important

Of course this only works if the asset isn't compressed ! But it's not that hard to disable the compression.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `RandomAccessFile` if you possibly can. `InputStream.skipBytes()` only works by reading the file.

Comment: It doesn't look like you can use assets with `RandomAccessFile`, you still would need to copy the file to cache first.